# SVN inside another SVN

Tags: svn

I have simple project that is in SVN and everything works fine.
I want to use code from **another** SVN server in folder inside this simple project.

How can I do this?

I want to have the ability to update code from this "other" SVN server later on.

```
svn co http://svnserverone.com/projects/trunk/ mjproject
svn co http://anotherserver.com/whatever/trunk/ mjproject/path/module
```

Thanks for your time and answers!

Oto

Comment: if your going to use externals you should look into branching your code and using a branch as external, so that in case you go rewriting the whole thing it doesn't affect you code that relies on the previus version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using something called svn:externals

I had to add a space to the http:// and the anotherserver due to the spam protection thing

```
cd mjproject/path/modules
svn propset svn:externals 'new_module_name http:// anotherserver.com/whatever/trunk/' .
```

property 'svn:externals' set on '.'

then commit:

```
svn ci -m "adding externals"
```

then do

```
svn up
```

References:
http://beerpla.net/2009/06/20/how-to-properly-set-svn-svnexternals-property-in-svn-command-line/